# Am I a person eater?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was in Markarth and I had to go into the burial chamber or whatever it's called. The lady said I was a person eater (I forgot the name). Am I actually a person eater or is she just saying that?!

Comment: did you mean cannibal?

Comment: Person eater make it sound much more enjoyable

Comment: You gotta love some [long pig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannibalism) it is tasty.

Answer (score 8):

This encounter is part of the quest [The Taste of Death](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Investigate_the_Hall_of_the_Dead) - Eola is making an assumption about your intentions in entering the hall, but whether or not you're a cannibal depends on how you handle this particular quest.  :)

Keep in mind that the reward for this quest,

> the [Ring of Namira](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ring_of_Namira), is a daedric artifact,

and it's missable.  There's an achievement

> ([Oblivion Walker](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Oblivion_Walker#Achievements)) related to collecting these artifacts.

If you care about such things, you should probably humor her.

Answer (score 3):

From your description it sounds like you've just started the [Taste of Death](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Taste_Of_Death) quest and met Eola, in which case she's just saying it and you haven't become a cannibal yet.

You will have the option, should you pursue the quest to become a cannibal or reject them.